# Materialize SASS package: do I need to include all the .js file manually?

Tags: sass, material-design, materialize

http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

In the SASS package there are lots of .js files, and I quickly go through materialize.js, it doesn't seem to be loading all those .js files, shall I include all those *.js files when I start my project with materialize?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, you need to include them manually, SASS Compiler doesn't affect JavaScript files in any way.

The only difference between those two packages is that Materialize SASS contains the source code, written in SASS. It's almost the same in every other aspect, so the usage is the same too.

Comment: "need no" or "need to"?

Comment: @shenkwen "need to", as if you were using a regular package of Materialize.